# Octave-'endfunction' command matched by 'endif'

Tags: octave

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
   sinlaw('?',150,30,39.8)
   parse error near line 30 of file 
   'endfunction' command matched by 'endif'
```

```octave
function [phi] = sinlaw (A,a,B,b)
If A==('?')
a=deg2rad(a)
b=deg2rad(b)
A=(B/sin(b))*sin(a) 
endif
if(a=='?')
a=deg2rad(asin((A/B)*sin(b)))
endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Octave input is case-sensitive.  "`If`" must be written as "`if`" to be recognized as an `if`.

Comment: I've added octave syntax-highlighting to your example: you can now see clearly that the top "If" is treated as a different kind of token. If your editor supports syntax highlighting (e.g. the octave build-tin editor), then this could have alerted you to your typo. (PS. proper indentation would also have helped!)

Answer (score 1):

While the syntax-check whines about matched by `endif`

### The problem is actually in the `If...` typo

Feel free to [test it here](https://tio.run/##VY/LDsIgEEX3fMXdSQ3x1ZjoojHtbxgX9KUkhhqt@vl4gdjHsGCGM3Mv01W9/jTOtW9b9aazOD9u5oIML2Pv@guJXEErFAolEiHAMC1yZBnZ4rTgI2JocKxurrunriWrAZQzUI4g90CiwNrbBcSzjAUFEBobW5t2cPaA3jNn7z21DvP8OXWLUTCqJ1NNXv/FhYgbS2C73yhvoJAySY@rA6cGGkBoGalzPw).

```
function [phi] = sinlaw ( A, a, B, b )

    if A == ( '?' )                                 %% this works, not the "If"
       a  = deg2rad( a )
       b  = deg2rad( b )
       A  = ( B / sin( b ) ) * sin( a ) 
    endif

    if ( a == '?' )
         a = deg2rad( asin( ( A / B ) * sin( b ) ) )
    endif

endfunction
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
sinlaw(  150, '?', 30, 39.8 )
sinlaw(  '?', 150, 30, 39.8 )
```

Comment: Thanks,  sorry give you an up-vote right away. I didn't notice the button