# 'endif' command matched by 'endfor' problem in octave

Tags: octave

```
for i=1:128
  if (Analysis(4,i) != 0)
  Analysis (5,i) = Analysis (3,i) ./ Analysis (4,i);
  else if (Analysis(4,i) == 0)
    Analysis (5,i) = 10;
  endif
endfor
```

I am new in octave. i am seeing this type of error " **'endif' command matched by 'endfor'** " . I cant understand the reason.

[N.B. [I checked this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288735/octave-endfunction-command-matched-by-endif) . It was not helpful.]

Comment: This is not MATLAB. MATLAB does not have `endfor` or `endif`. Removing [tag:matlab] tag.

Comment: To answer your question, there's no space between `else` and `if`. It's `elseif`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As beaker pointed out in the comments, the correct syntax is `elseif`, not `else if`. The latter effectively means your code is now equivalent to this:

```
for i=1:128
    if (Analysis(4,i) != 0)
        Analysis (5,i) = Analysis (3,i) ./ Analysis (4,i);
    else
        if (Analysis(4,i) == 0)
            Analysis (5,i) = 10;
        endif
    endfor
```

In other words, octave is letting you know that it has encountered an `endfor`, where it expected that an `endif` should have occurred first.

Comment: also see this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61164622/4183191